# Additional gap between inline-block and its container

Tags: html, css

My code is

**HTML:**

```
<div id = "container">
  <div id = "content">
      Text
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

#container {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   font-size: 24px;
}

#content {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ry2DY/)**

There is the same issue with `line-height: 60px`: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kJtq/) and also with centering div: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VQWhs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `font-size: 0;` for parent container and `font-size: your_size;` for children.

Modified example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ry2DY/2/